# Tcl-Tk Find a specific word in a file

Tags: file, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to find a matching row in a a text file having 4 columns of numbers like this:

```
number                coordinates
101138  0.420335 -.238945 .1446484
101139  .4134844 -0.2437 6.7484e-2
101140  .4140046 -.243681 7.3344e-2
```

I need to read the text file and find a specific number in the first column and plot only its coordinates.

This is my code in which I try to find the coordinates for number "101138" but something is not working because there is no match found.

```
set Output [open "Output1.txt" w]
set FileInput     [open "Input.txt" r]

set filecontent [read $FileInput]
set inputList [split $filecontent "\n"]

set Text [lsearch -all -inline $inputList "101138"]
foreach elem $Text {
    puts $Output "[lindex $elem 1] [lindes $elem 2] [lindex $elem 3]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a list element that exactly matches your given value "101138". However your list is constructed from lines which have multiple whitespace delimited columns. You need to amend your search to match this value in the correct column.

One method would be to split each line again and perform an equals match on the correct column. Another might be to use a glob or regexp expression that actually matches the inputs. ie:

```
% set lst {"123 abc def" "456 efg ijk" "789 zxc cvb"}
"123 abc def" "456 efg ijk" "789 zxc cvb"
% lsearch -all -inline $lst "456*"
{456 efg ijk}
% lsearch -all -inline -regexp $lst "^456"
{456 efg ijk}
```

The second line does a standard (glob) match looking for a list element beginning with 456 followed by anything.

The last line searches for a list element that begins with "456" using regular expression matching.